# Bash command wait until next full second

Tags: bash, datetime, wait, milliseconds

I'm asking for how to wait for the nextfull second? I dont mean sleep 1!
For example we have the time 07:45:06.729.
The last 729 means the milliseconds.
So how we can i say wait until next full second? It would be 07:45:07.000

Thanks ;)

Comment: Are you sure bash is the right tool for implementing this?

Comment: That's a good point, you might want to implement a custom sleep-until-next-second program in C, rather than running `date` and `sleep`.  Depending on your use-case and expected system load, writing more of your logic in another language might make sense, too.

Comment: And then what? Start another program which will take arbitrarily long to load? Another program which runs in a non-real-time multitasking operating system which gives no guarantees about processor availability and has no concern for determinancy? Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

This is like Matt's answer, but doesn't have a busy-wait to try to wake up early.  This simplifies things a *lot*, because we never have to care about anything but the fractional-second part of the current time.

Use GNU `date +%N` to get the nanoseconds portion of the current time, and `sleep` for 1 - that.

```
sleep_to_next_second(){
    #TODO: check for 0000 and don't sleep at all, instead of for 0.10000
    sleep 0.$(printf '%04d' $((10000 - 10#$(date +%4N))))
}
```

(FIXME: to fix the special-case bug, you'd just do a text compare for 0000.  If so, you're already at the start of a second; don't sleep.  So capture the printf result into a `local duration=$(...)` variable, or `printf -v duration` to print into a variable.)

The tricks are:

- numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal in a bash arithmetic context, so use `10#$date` to [force base10](http://blog.famzah.net/2010/08/07/beware-of-leading-zeros-in-bash-numeric-variables/).
- Since bash can only do integer math, the obvious thing is to use fixed-point thousandths of a second or something, and tack on a leading decimal point.  This makes leading zeros essential, so that you sleep for 0.092 seconds, not 0.92.  I used `printf '%04d'` to format my numbers.

experimental testing:

```
# echo instead of sleep to see what numbers we generate
while true;do echo 0.$(printf '%04d' $((10000 - 10#$(date +%4N))));done

...
0.0049
0.0035
0.0015
0.10000    ##### minor bug: sleeps for 0.1 sec if the time was bang-on a ten-thousandth
0.9987
0.9973
0.9960

while true;do date +"%s %N"; sleep 0.$(printf '%04d' $((10000 - 10#$(date +%4N))));done
1445301422 583340443
1445301423 003697512
1445301424 003506054
1445301425 003266620
1445301426 003776955
1445301427 003921242
1445301428 003018890
1445301429 002652820
# So typical accuracy is 0.003 secs after the rollover to the next second, on a near-idle desktop
```

Ubuntu 15.04: GNU bash/date/sleep on Linux 3.19 on Intel i5-2500k, idling at 1.6GHz, turbo 3.8GHz.

Comment: What does the `#` do in `10#$(date +%4N)`?

Comment: @bigjosh: `10#` stops leading zeros in the `date` output from causing a number to be interpreted as octal instead of decimal.  See the first bullet point in my answer: "the tricks are..."

Comment: Was specifically curious about the `#` notation - never saw that before! Found this... "numbers take the form "[BASE'#']N", where "BASE" is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base" [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html). Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if anyone else is trying to see the "bang-on" bug, it happens when the  `date +%4N` returns `0000`. In this case, then match ends up being `100000-0000`, which results in an answer of `100000`, which turns into `sleep 0.100000` because the sleep delay is generated by sticking the string `0.` in front of the above math result. BASH is not for the faint of types types! :)

Answer (score 1):

The GNU sleep command accepts floating point parameters.
So you could calculate the exact time to wait and call sleep with the result.

See https://superuser.com/questions/222301/unix-sleep-until-the-specified-time

and https://serverfault.com/questions/469247/how-do-i-sleep-for-a-millisecond-in-bash-or-ksh

Comment: But beware that sleeping on most OS is relatively imprecise due to process scheduling. It will be hard to get closer than 10ms. Maybe it is enough if the specified time has passed?

Comment: Linux has had high-accuracy sleeps for years.  It sets a hardware timer to fire at the appropriate time.   http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55323/79808 says that Linux has had high-accuracy timing since 2.6.21.  Video players like `mplayer` used to have options to use root access to get higher timing accuracy, but that's no longer needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, but both out of scope in this context and scheduler arbitration still occurs. - You cannot assume it did not sleep considerably more. Realtime.. yes, but even more out of scope.

Comment: It's possible your process sleeps longer than you wanted, but I think video players *usually* get woken up in time even as normal-priority non-root processes, without busy-waiting or using any realtime system calls.  With high system load, where all CPUs are busy, sure you could get some longer sleeps.  I think we can both agree that the best we can say is: Depending on the use-case and expected system conditions, you might or might not get good results.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a timer solution.

It requires GNU `date` which can do nanoseconds with `%N` and a `sleep` that can do decimals, which GNU does and some others do.

Your mileage will vary on a heavily loaded system. This will skip seconds if it has to.

If accuracy on a loaded system is not that important then `safety` can be lower (or just use Peter's simpler solution). The higher it is the more processor time you take, but it has a slightly higher chance of being on time on a heavily loaded system. Past a point, you're just wasting cpu time. Even then, if your system has better things to schedule, this will wait.

```
# ms to spend busy waiting * 10
safety=100

while true; do
  if [ "$(date +%s)" != "$last_sec" ]; then

    # Do whatever you need to here
    date +"%S.%N"

    # Then figure out how much to sleep until just 
    # before the next second. 
    sec_ns="$(date +"%s %4N")"
    sec=${sec_ns:0:-5}
    ms=${sec_ns:11}
    last_sec=$sec
    let sleep=10000-10#$ms-$safety
    sleep 0.$(printf '%04d' $sleep)
  fi
done
```

The calls to `date` and `sleep` are external binaries so there is some overhead to executing them. As mentioned in the comments, bash might not be the best tool for the job.

<strike>Also note this will fail after Sat Nov 20 17:46:39 UTC 2286 due to the use of substrings. Hopefully our computer overlords have removed bash from their os by then.</strike> Thanks for ruining my joke Peter =)

Running both

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ /tmp/wait_seconds.sh 
32.376187825
33.002727030
34.001005707
35.001850686
36.002232134
37.001802235
^C
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ while sleep 0.$(printf '%04d' $((10000 - 10#$(date +%4N) - 1))); do date +"%S.%N"; done
41.006809812
42.005389515
43.005793726
44.004930099
45.004829293
46.005988337
```

Comment: You can avoid the substring error in 2286 by putting the fixed-length portion of the output first.  Also, you don't need the loop unless `sleep` could receive a signal that stops it early.  Getting rid of that would mean you only need `date +%3N`.  `sleep` is guaranteed to sleep at least as long as you request.

Comment: Yeah I was more thinking of a second timer as opposed to the first second. The intention of the short sleep and loop is the opposite though.  For sleep's that _will_ go longer on a busy system. It also removes the delay between the generation of the sleep variable, and running the sleep.  It's generally in the 1-2ms range. On heavily loaded system it's $safety give it more chance. At the cost of cpu, of course.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now.  I kinda stopped reading once I decided it looked way more complicated than I thought should be needed.  You can still make the split safer by putting using `date +'%3N %s'`, so the fixed-length field is first.  Or you could use negative values for the ranges, to count from the end of the string.  Also, are you sure you need to run `date` twice inside the while loop?  Why not check this iteration vs. previous iteration, with initial `date` setup outside the loop?

Comment: You might remove the delay between `date` exiting and running `sleep`, but you run `date` again and do some bash logic before running the actual command that we're delaying for.  I don't think you're getting closer to running the command at the start of a new second than my version, busy system or not.

Comment: There was some unnecessary stuff in there for the initial date, cleaned it up a bit. The two dates are again for a timer, to account for the run time of "whatever".  It does still seem to get closer on my local machine, especially during a gcc compile of gcc.

Comment: What if you structured it like `while outerloop; some_command; date; while busywait; done; done`, so the busy-wait portion only runs `date` once per iteration?

Comment: The busy portion of the wait already only runs one `date` per iteration, to check if the new second has arrived. The only time two `date`s are run is when it hits the new second, and then you need to get the current `%N` value to sleep until just before the next second.

Comment: in any case it's all pretty academic because at this level.. you shouldn't be using bash anyway =)

Comment: Oh, I see, because one of the `date` commands inside the loop is inside the `if` condition.  derp, silly me, it was like that the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash

```
sleep echo "scale=3; $((1000 -$(echo $(cut -d '.' -f2 <<< "07:45:06.729"))))/1000"|bc
```

Let me break this down a little since it is confusing

`$(cut -d '.' -f2 <<< "07:45:06.729")`  # This will get the milliseconds portion

building on the above command line

`echo "scale=3; $((1000 -$(echo $(cut -d '.' -f2 <<< "07:45:06.729"))))/1000"|bc` # This will gave you the fraction

After this pass the remainder to the `sleep` 
Edited: Shorter bash codes used

Comment: Are you sure this works when the time is something like xxx.005?  Leading zeros in numbers mean it gets interpreted as octal in a bash arithmetic context, without a leading `10#`.  And also, the result won't be zero-padded.  So instead of sleeping for .092 seconds, you would sleep for .92.  Matt's answer handles this (and uses date's `%N` format to get nanoseconds.)

Comment: What the Questioner is wants is that fraction of a second for the sleep command...not anything greater than 1...read carefully " So how we can i say wait until next full second? "

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought the OP wanted.  Your implementation has bugs though:  1000 - 910 = 90, which would lead to a sleep of 0.90 seconds, not the desired sleep of 0.090 seconds.  And you also need to avoid treating the three decimal digits as base-8 if they start with a zero.  Both bugs would lead to sleeping too long (but still not more than one second), so it does still satisfy the OP's criteria, but not optimally.

Comment: see my answer for a similar idea but using bash-builtin `printf` to avoid the leading-zero problem.  I think my answer is better, because it has less overhead.  And you still have the octal-bug in the math you're still doing with bash.  I think your inner `echo` is redundant, too.  Just put `$(cut...)` in the arithmetic context.  Or use bash substring expansion to chop off the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are very clever BASH, but ultimately I kept running into strange edge case problems trying to do it only in BASH so I wrote a trivial C program instead that works perfectly every time and is totally simple and understandable.

```
// Wait until the next second rolls over
// Use sleep rather than polling


#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>



int main(void) {

    unsigned int microseconds;

    struct timeval  tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);


    // Calculate time until next round second...

    microseconds = 1000000 - (tv.tv_usec);

    usleep(microseconds);

    return(0);
}
```

https://github.com/bigjosh/De-Harak-Clock-Controller/blob/master/nextsecond.c

Build the utility with the commands...

```
gcc nextsecond.c
chmod +x nextsecond
```

You can test that it works by running...

```
./nextsecond; date "+%N"
```

It will print the number of nanoseconds since the last round second, which should always be less than 010000000, which is 10,000,000ns, which is 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function without any magic

```
function sleepUntilTheNextSecond() {
    local currentTimeMilliseconds
    currentTimeMilliseconds=$(date +%s%3N)
    local currentTimeSeconds=$(( currentTimeMilliseconds / 1000 ))
    local targetTimeMilliseconds=$(( (currentTimeSeconds + 1) * 1000 ))
    local sleepMilliseconds=$(( targetTimeMilliseconds - currentTimeMilliseconds ))
    if (( sleepMilliseconds > 1000 )); then
        echo "Invalid sleepMilliseconds (> 1000): $sleepMilliseconds"
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep "0.$sleepMilliseconds"
}
```

Tested on `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`